# Force git to use other folder for /tmp

Tags: git

I have a server with a git repository. The hard disk where the root partition isn't working properly. The git repository is in `/home` which is located in another HD.

At the moment the partition with the root folder is in readonly mode so I can not write anything there.
When I push to the git repo, it fails because it tries to write in `/tmp` before doing all the merging stuff.

Is it possible to tell git to use `/home/tmp` for this operations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may change the $TMPDIR env variable :

```
export TMPDIR=/your/tmp/folder/
```

Comment: I thought that; but how do I change it. I logged and put this command in the `.bashrc`. If I log with ssh the variable is correctly exported. But doing the push still tries to wirte in a readonly mode hard disk.

Comment: I finally do it. The repo was also in the readonly partition. Once I move it everything works fine. Thanks